# PHP array manipulation: Convert array to matrix

Tags: php, arrays

I have php array like this:

```
$array = array('1', '2', '3', '5', '8', '11');
```

But I want to get this one:

```
$result['1']['2']['3']['5']['8']['11'];
```

Note: Number of elements in array $array are not constant.

Comment: What is $result['1']['2']['3']['5']['8']['11']? Is it a 6-dimensional array?, or do you want an structure containing 6 arrays each with a single element from your original array?

Comment: Just to be clear: PHP doesn't have "matrix" or "6-dimensional" arrays (very few languages have). What you show in your result are simply nested arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result = array();
foreach (array_reverse($array) as $key) {
    $result = array($key => $result);
}

// or, with PHP 5.4 array syntax and functional code:

$result = array_reduce(array_reverse($array), function (array $result, $key) {
    return [$key => $result];
}, []);
```

Not sure if this is really what you imagine it will be though.